# Spring jpa saving data during rollback

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I know that sounds strange the question but the reasoning is quite simple.
I've an server side app developed with Spring+Hibernate.

I've a custom servlet:

```
@Transactional
@Component
public class ReceivingSms implements HttpRequestHandler {
...
...
...
@Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ....reading data from parameters and store into the db....
    entityManager.persist(someEntities);

    //at some point I found that there is some error and I've to rollback the entire transaction
    if(error){
        //HERE I WANT TO SAVE A LOG ON DB
        throw new RuntimeException("Error");
    }
}
```

The reason is this:

- I'm reading parameters that arrives to the servlet
- I store on the db some data derived from these parameters
- At some point I understand that there is an error and I can't complete the process. So I throw a RuntimeException to rollback the entire transaction
- before return, I'd like to save a particular entity(a kind of log) in the db. Howewer also if I try, this persist is rolled back from the RuntimeException

From here my question: there is a way to store an entity in the db and rollback the rest of a transaction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call another transactional service, whose method is annotated with

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

to save the log entry.